# Does the consistance of collections in a graph in ArangoDB guaranteed?

Tags: arangodb, aql, foxx

Let say I have a collection node N and a edges collection E. Together , I created a graph G from N and E. In the document, Arango guarantee the consistency of graph G such as no dangling edges when nodes are deleted, etc. Does this consistency hold in situations such as:

1. Used Foxx, delete 1 node (Thus making edges have 1 null in the _from and _to)
2. Used Foxx, delete nodes using [collection API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/DataModeling/Documents/DocumentMethods.html) (not using AQL)
3. Used AQL, delete directly in nodes/edges collection without traversal

I asked this question due to the fact that my query does return some null value of nodes and I would like to understand more about this topic for inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming and outgoing edges of a vertex are removed together with the vertex if you use the [Graph API](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-vertex). You can use the General Graph module in Foxx and arangosh. Some drivers provide wrappers for this Graph API. The General Graph HTTP API is called [Gharial](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/HTTP/Gharial/Vertices.html#remove-a-vertex).

If you remove vertices by other means, like a [db](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/DataModeling/Documents/DatabaseMethods.html#remove) or [collection](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/DataModeling/Documents/DocumentMethods.html#remove) object in Foxx or arangosh, through the Web UI, with AQL or via HTTP endpoints for like `DELETE /_api/document/{document-handle}`, then you need to [delete connected edges yourself](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Examples/RemoveVertex.html) or accept dangling edges.